# Why does Package not close underlying stream?

Tags: c#, stream, package, dispose

I am using a `Package` opened with the following code

```
Package package = Package.Open(stream, fileMode, fileAccess);
```

where `stream` is basically a `MemoryStream`. Now if I call `package.Close()` the memory stream is still open.

When I use the overloaded method for open where I enter a path to a file and close the package, the file handle is disposed. When I open a `StreamReader` and close it, it disposes the underlying stream.

Why does the `Package` class not dispose the underlying stream?

Comment: When you say that is still open, do you mean that `CanRead`/`CanSeek`/`CanWrite` properties are still true or that you have still access to the `MemoryStream` buffer?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I have a specialized class with memory stream as the base class, where I basically wait for the stream to close and than do some work (write it back to the file system). This does not happen if the stream is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

You made a stream - you opened it, you made something that can use the stream. However, the stream is still there. So yes, you need to close and dispose of the stream after

Comment: To be fair: Several classes that use streams will close the stream by default, for example readers and writers, and you have to take strange precautions sometimes if you want to keep the stream after you're done with the writer.

Comment: The same applies to `StreamReader` or any other wrapper which only uses the stream. But they do close the stream.

Comment: true, but as a whole its sounding like its not closing it... so

Comment: @BugFinder Yes of course, Captain Obvious :-) Still, the question is not a dumb as you make it look, when parts of the framework auto-close streams and other parts don't. Of course the answer is: then close it yourself...

Comment: I hoped to understand the inconsistency between the `StreamReader` like wrapper and the `Package` class.